# Could someone please clarify dictionaries for me?

Tags: dictionary, data-structures, tree, linked-list, key

I am in a data Structures course and separately I believe I understand things, like I know that there are different kinds of trees with different rules, and I know things like that a stack and a queue are just different specific ways to implement a Linked List or an ArrayList depending on what you are wanting to do. However, now I have a family tree project, which says that I need to read in a pre and post order traversal which contain in a list all these people with their first and last names and their gender, and it says I need to construct a general tree and print out the level order traversal as a comma separated list HOWEVER; I have to have a unique key for each person and create two dictionaries and a queue and a list to do this??? The instructions are over 10 pages long and I am actually quite scared. It is due Tuesday and I don't even know 
if a dictionary is just another way to implement a linked list?

Comment: In computer science, an associative array, map, symbol table, or dictionary is an abstract data type composed of a collection of (key, value) pairs, such that each possible key appears just once in the collection. Operations associated with this data type allow: the addition of a pair to the collection.  tldr - dictionaries are made up of a key (unique identifier) and value pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary can be implemented as a tree. Typically, each node would store two links to child nodes (two children -> binary tree). So I guess you could view this structure as a linked list (with forks) but nobody calls it a linked list. It's a tree.

You can also store a tree in a plain array. Typically, stacks and queues are also based on plain arrays because it's more efficient. They are not different ways to implement a list. They are different ways to organize data and they all have different pros and cons.

A dictionary (or map/associative array/symbol table) allows you to create mappings like
`String (Key) => String (Value)`. Conceptually you could use it for a mapping of `Name => Gender`.

```
map.insert("Daddy", "male");
map.insert("Mommy", "female");
map.insert("Sister Olga", "female");
map.insert("Brother Kevin", "male");

map.get("Mommy"); // returns "female"
```

If implemented as a tree, a map is always sorted by keys. You build it like any other tree but you need a function to compare the keys (a `less than` or `<` operator for example). In the case above you would compare the names (Strings).

The tree will automatically guarantee unique keys. I quess you need the queue for breadth-first traversal and the linked list for storing the results.

You weren't very clear about what exactly the problem is, but I hope this helped.

*Edit:* Maybe I understand your confusion now. You can also implement a dictionary as an array or a list. As Kritner said in the comments. The concept of dictionary is abstract and doesn't define how it's implemented.

An efficient implementation as an array or list would require you to sort the elements and access them via binary search for example. I'd go for the implementation as a tree if you already have something to build upon. Better grades for sure.

Comment: thank you! I'm sorry I took so long to do this, I was new to the site ( :

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. It's relieving to see whether an answer was helpful or not.